# Workflow for Transferring Data from One App To Another

Tags: macos, automation

The purpose of this question is to find out whether there is a way to create a certain kind of program to run on macOS.

Basically, I need a program that can look at data streaming on a screen in an app installed on macOS.  I have no access to the data except with my eyes looking at in through this app.  I am wondering if there is a way to make a program to save a copy of the data as it streams in (inputs).  While that is going on, the program needs to manipulate a block of records of that data, create one output record using rules I can program, then enter the output data into a form within a different app from a different software maker, completely separate from the app streaming the data.

In other words, the program I need will bridge data from one app, process the data, and enter results in another app by putting the data into a form on the screen.  The program receiving the data cannot read data from my computer anywhere except through the form on the screen.

A robot could be built to do this, but this would be nuts.  The robot would need a camera to see the data on my screen, software for translating what it sees into data files, a processor with software for manipulating the data to determine the output data, and a mechanical arm for moving the mouse to select the other program, and for typing the data through my keyboard into the other program.

Is there a way to program this without using a robot?

Comment: Exactly what are these mystery applications and what kind of data are they using?

Comment: The apps are used for trading currency futures.  One app streams live trading data.  The other app is for making trades.  I do not have the apps at this time.  They have been described to me by someone else.  I am trying to find out whether it is possible to use Apple scripts or some other technology to read the data displayed in one app and enter data into another.  I am sure I write a program to translate the data stream into trades.  I don't know if it is possible to write a program to access the data from one app and enter it into another.